# Trivial combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

We have 10 people and only the first three get medals. In how many ways can these people get medals.
The answer is: $720$, but I thought it should be $\binom{10}{3}$, and then we get $120$.

Can somebody explain why it is $720$.

Comment: Because it matters which medal a contestant gets.  There are $120$ ways to select the three contestants who win medals, and for each of those, there are $6$ ways to decide which contestant wins gold, which wins silver, and which wins bronze.

Comment: Gold goes to one among $10$, silver to one among $9$ and bronze to one among $8$, hence $10\cdot9\cdot8$.